# Why 1920x1080 videos are displayed very slow using JavaFX

Tags: javafx, video-processing

I am trying to play some videos with resolution 1920x1080 using JavaFX frame by frame because I want to apply some modifications on each frame but when I start the program I see the video played very slow.

What is the cause? How can I improve it?

How I do it:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
        while (runnable) {
            if (webSource.grab()) {
                try {
                    webSource.retrieve(frame);
                    numberOfFrames++;
                    Mat resize_blur_Img = frame.clone();

                    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(resize_blur_Img, resize_blur_Img, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2);


                    Mat fgMask = new Mat();
                    mog2.apply(resize_blur_Img, fgMask, 0.01);

                    Mat output = new Mat();
                    Mat closeElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(7, 7),
                            new Point(3, 3));
                    Imgproc.morphologyEx(fgMask, output, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, closeElement);
                    Imgproc.morphologyEx(output, output, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, closeElement);

                    Imgproc.threshold(output, output, 127, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
                    contourImg = new Mat();
                    contourImg = output.clone();
                    findContours(contourImg);

                    Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
                    image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));
                    BufferedImage bufferedImage = (BufferedImage) image;
                    imgView.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null));

                    Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", output, mem2);
                    image2 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem2.toArray()));
                    BufferedImage bufferedImage2 = (BufferedImage) image2;
                    imgViewLeft3.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage2, null));

                    if (runnable == false) {
                        System.out.println("Going to wait() -> DaemonThread");
                        this.wait();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            } else {
                runnable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert, but you might find some performance gain with `imgView.setImage(new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray())))`. Additionally, this method looks like it's running on non application thread, so it would be more appropriate to wrap the `setImage()` with a `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: Another thing, if all the cloning are not required, it is best not to do that. You are giving a lot of stress to the garbage collector by creating non-necessary objects, which happen to be terribly big.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jai. If I change video bitrate to 3000 and resolution lower it works better.......but that's not what I want